# WPF: Click And Drag To Select Multiple CheckBoxes

Tags: wpf, checkbox, visual-studio-2013, multi-select

**The effect I want to achieve:**

1. Left mouse button is held down.
2. Mouse moves.
3. Toggle any checkbox the mouse passes over.

Simple, right? ;-;

Thanks.

Comment: you will realize it is not that simple if you start to write some code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too hard.

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Checkbox_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (checkbox != null)
            {
                checkbox.IsChecked = !checkbox.IsChecked;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
            if (checkbox != null)
            {
                checkbox.IsChecked = !checkbox.IsChecked;
                checkbox.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="ClickAndDrag.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox MouseEnter="Checkbox_OnMouseEnter" GotMouseCapture="UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture"/>
    <CheckBox MouseEnter="Checkbox_OnMouseEnter" GotMouseCapture="UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture"/>
    <CheckBox MouseEnter="Checkbox_OnMouseEnter" GotMouseCapture="UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture"/>
    <CheckBox MouseEnter="Checkbox_OnMouseEnter" GotMouseCapture="UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture"/>
    <CheckBox MouseEnter="Checkbox_OnMouseEnter" GotMouseCapture="UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture"/>
    <CheckBox MouseEnter="Checkbox_OnMouseEnter" GotMouseCapture="UIElement_OnGotMouseCapture"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The reason for releasing the mouse capture is to prevent a checkbox from swallowing all the events when it is clicked.